# Vagrant: couldn't open file base

Tags: configuración, vagrant

Buenas gente, soy nuevo utilizando Vagrant. Instale vagrant version 1.9.1. , cree una imagen de precise32.box utilizando el siguiente [tutorial](https://styde.net/como-crear-un-entorno-de-desarrollo-virtual-con-vagrant/)
cuando ejecuto el comando vagrant up, me salta el siguiente error.

> couldn't open file base

Desde ya agradecería cualquier ayuda.!!

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El tutorial que seguiste tiene dos errores, debes modificar la imagen base y corregir la palabra provsion por provision, en el Vagrantfile esas dos líneas quedan así:

```
 config.vm.box = "precise32"
 config.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap.sh"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias tutmosis. Saludos.